# Исключить символ % из таблицы (DataFrame) для анализа данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=5, random_state=322)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42.86%
```

Как можно исключить знак процента из таблицы?

```js
2018-04-06  2018-04-07  2018-04-08  2018-04-09  2018-04-10  2018-04-11  2018-04-12  2018-04-15  2018-04-16  2018-04-17  2018-04-18  2018-04-19  2018-04-20  2018-04-21  2018-04-22  2018-04-23
angry   8.00%   0.00%   0.00%   33.33%  0.38%   0.00%   5.00%   0.00%   0.00%   9.52%   14.58%  18.42%  23.53%  2.49%   42.86%  0.00%
disgust 0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%
fear    8.00%   0.00%   38.89%  8.33%   48.11%  14.00%  18.33%  40.00%  20.00%  28.57%  12.50%  5.26%   11.76%  0.92%   14.29%  28.57%
happy   0.00%   0.00%   5.56%   0.00%   1.52%   0.00%   5.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   10.42%  0.00%   1.96%   0.52%   0.00%   0.00%
neutral 12.00%  71.43%  5.56%   16.67%  46.97%  55.00%  26.67%  30.00%  53.33%  19.05%  18.75%  42.11%  13.73%  93.85%  28.57%  57.14%
sad 68.00%  28.57%  50.00%  41.67%  2.65%   30.00%  45.00%  30.00%  26.67%  42.86%  43.75%  31.58%  47.06%  2.23%   14.29%  14.29%
surprise    4.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.38%   1.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%   2.63%   1.96%   0.00%   0.00%   0.00%
```

UPD

```
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-8c601ad4b9f1> in <module>()
      2 
      3 clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=5, random_state=322)
----> 4 clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    245         """
    246         # Validate or convert input data
--> 247         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    248         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    249         if sample_weight is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '42.86%'`
```

Comment: Хм, а где сама таблица находится? И можно полный стек в вопросе указать, а то непонятно с какой функции ошибка полетела

Comment: Этих данных хватит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) позволяет заменить строки/подстроки во всем DataFrame. После этого можно применить [pd.to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) ко всем столбцам, преобразовав их в числовые значения:

```
In [7]: df = (df.replace(r'[^\d\.]', '', regex=True)
                .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
```

Результат:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
          2018-04-06  2018-04-07  2018-04-08  2018-04-09  2018-04-10  2018-04-11  2018-04-12  2018-04-15  2018-04-16  2018-04-17  \
angry            8.0        0.00        0.00       33.33        0.38         0.0        5.00         0.0        0.00        9.52
disgust          0.0        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00         0.0        0.00         0.0        0.00        0.00
fear             8.0        0.00       38.89        8.33       48.11        14.0       18.33        40.0       20.00       28.57
happy            0.0        0.00        5.56        0.00        1.52         0.0        5.00         0.0        0.00        0.00
neutral         12.0       71.43        5.56       16.67       46.97        55.0       26.67        30.0       53.33       19.05
sad             68.0       28.57       50.00       41.67        2.65        30.0       45.00        30.0       26.67       42.86
surprise         4.0        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.38         1.0        0.00         0.0        0.00        0.00

          2018-04-18  2018-04-19  2018-04-20  2018-04-21  2018-04-22  2018-04-23
angry          14.58       18.42       23.53        2.49       42.86        0.00
disgust         0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00
fear           12.50        5.26       11.76        0.92       14.29       28.57
happy          10.42        0.00        1.96        0.52        0.00        0.00
neutral        18.75       42.11       13.73       93.85       28.57       57.14
sad            43.75       31.58       47.06        2.23       14.29       14.29
surprise        0.00        2.63        1.96        0.00        0.00        0.00

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]:
2018-04-06    float64
2018-04-07    float64
2018-04-08    float64
2018-04-09    float64
2018-04-10    float64
2018-04-11    float64
2018-04-12    float64
2018-04-15    float64
2018-04-16    float64
2018-04-17    float64
2018-04-18    float64
2018-04-19    float64
2018-04-20    float64
2018-04-21    float64
2018-04-22    float64
2018-04-23    float64
dtype: object
```

PS лучше и проще конвертировать данные **до** разбивки на тренировочный и проверочный сеты.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @potemin, всегда рад помочь. :)

Comment: @potemin, у вас в профайле шикарна картинка, жалко мне раньше не попадалась...